# Rails: set value of input with javascript and save to db, get nill

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to save the html of the current page of the user. I created a small form and a jquery function in order to add the html in the input value attribute. It works well as I can see the value is filled but when I save, I get the following error:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for "/build", method: "post" do %>
  <input type="text" name="input" id="input" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
def save
    Content.create html: @params[:input], user_id: current_user.id, last_update: Time.now
    redirect_to "/build"
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
params[:input]
```

not

```
@params[:input]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no instance variable named `params` (`@params`). You should use the `params` helper method.

`params[:input]`